# Query Dictionary where keys have line breaks?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dictionary populated based on the headers of the columns of my worksheet. Some of the headers have line breaks. Is there a way to modify my code where I can query the dictionary of these values?

I've tried inserting "vbnewline" between the values, and it was unsuccessful

```
Sheets(UnPref).Range("A" & y).Value = Sheets("New Item Entry").Cells(z, hedDict("REQUESTOR")).Value
Sheets(UnPref).Range("B" & y).Value = Sheets("New Item Entry").Cells(z, hedDict("ORG")).Value
Sheets(UnPref).Range("C" & y).Value = Sheets("New Item Entry").Cells(z, hedDict("SHIP TO LOCATION")).Value
Sheets(UnPref).Range("D" & y).Value = Sheets("New Item Entry").Cells(z, hedDict("MRI NUMBER")).Value
Sheets(UnPref).Range("E" & y).Value = Sheets("New Item Entry").Cells(z, hedDict("ITEM IDENTIFIER" & vbNewLine & "USE UPPER CASE" & vbNewLine & "MANDATORY")).Value
```

Comment: Edit your question and show some test data and code

Comment: I've added the example code, I hope that makes it more clear?

Basically, an example header would be:
'ITEM IDENTIFIER
'USE UPPER CASE
'MANDATORY

all in one cell that I'm trying to reference

Comment: Not quite ... are your sure the headers contain vbCrLf (vbNewLine) or just vbLf or vbCr? Have you tried debugging the dictionary and check the actual keys?

Comment: I don’t really know how to check the dictionary, best I know how to check the values of the dictionary is to save a random value as a variable(I did this by creating an inverse dictionary) and putting that value in a msgbox. And the msgbox printed out across multiple lines I’ll check out the vbCrLf and see if I can apply it to my code. Thank you

Comment: If the headers are cell text, chances are the line break is vbCr.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I’ll try that!

Comment: Line breaks in an Excel cell are typically Chr(10) (vbLf)

Comment: I’ll try that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @TimWilliams - +1 for correction.

Comment: **Manual** line breaks entered in a cell with Alt+Enter will be `vbLf`. VBA code writing to a cell can very well write `vbNewLine` line breaks as it should. If a cell contains `vbNewLine`, then it contains both `vbCr` and `vbLf`, and if you're stripping line breaks from cells then removing only `vbLf` will leave `vbCr` characters in every cell that was written with `vbNewLine`.

Comment: ...which leads me to my vote-to-close as *unclear what you're asking*, since I've just now written `"a" & vbNewLine & "b"` into a cell, with the expected outcome. Exactly what does "unsuccessful" mean?

Comment: @TimWilliams vbLf worked! Thank you so much! You are a lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 0):

`vbNewLine` is `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`. i.e. `vbCr & vbLf`, while a newline character within a cell is `Chr(10)` only, i.e. vbLf.

Either replace `vbLf` by a space **when building your dictionary** from the column headers (this typically would be more efficient; you could then easily refer to an element as e.g. `"ITEM IDENTIFIER MANDATORY"`):

`hedDict(Replace(theColumnHeader, vbLf, " ", Compare:=VbCompareMethod.vbBinaryCompare)) = theValue`

Or: replace vbNewLine in your code sample by `vbLf`.

Comment: "a newline character within a cell is Chr(10) only" - only if it was manually entered with *Alt+Enter*. If it was written by VBA code using `vbNewLine`, then it contains `vbNewLine`.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying the `vbNewLine` is intended to be *platform-specific" - ie it's the same as `vbCrLf` on Windows but not on a Mac?